# Parsing text with HTML tags into NSAttributedString

Tags: html, parsing, nsattributedstring

I have a string containing HTML tags like this:

```
 @"Lorem ipsum... <b>Bold sting..</b>, then <em>emphasized sting...</em> 
normal text normal text <b>Bold sting..</b> etc...."
```

I would like to store this different pieces in an attributed string. Those who are out of the tags should have a Times font, black stroke color and a font size of 14.0, the others should have the same attributes plus the bold/emphasized one.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I found this [guide](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/how-to-create-a-simple-magazine-app-with-core-text): but I'm a little bit confused on how to use the NSRegularExpression class..

Answer (score 1):

I guess, what you are looking for is [DTCoreText](https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText) library